# What happens to the bounty of a migrated question?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious to know what happens to the bounty just before the question on which it is set is migrated to an other SE website.

P.S.

Inspired from the comment to this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76120/possible-for-lync-skype-for-business-to-adopt-activesync-style-policies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search on [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bounty+migrated) seems to indicate that such question can only be migrated by mods (and not by the standard voting process) following a specific manual procedure, this procedure involving "*to clear the bounty*" which means it will be closed and refunded.